# Froyoporting, vendor & device folder, and build for a device with tapas

Tags: android, android-build

i try to build Froyo for a given dev board, but i don't know how to configure the source tree, especially where should put the board specific code and the board configuration mkf ile, either in vendor or device ?

I first put my board specific code and config file in the vendor folder as:

`vendor\cpyname\the_product_1\`, with BoardConfig.mk that describe my board configuration.

I then have `vendor\cpyname\product\` with the_product_1.mk to start the source tree build.

can't build with tapas, when giving product name (the_product_1), i get an error

```
build/core/product_configuration.mk
the_product_1 not found.
```

I also try with the device folder, like:

```
device\the_product_1\ with BoardConfig.mk, 
and device\the_product_1\product\ with the_product_1.mk
```

tapas give the same result.

Note that first configuration can build and generate image with `make PRODUCT-the_product_1-eng`

I also personally find the build process quite obscure and missing documentation.   Please help :)

Lionel

Comment: Maybe the android-porting mailing list would be a good place to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Froyo and the after use devices  instead of vendor directory ,you will find sample there.